# Find the area between $r=a\cos(\theta)$ and $r=a(1+\cos(\theta))$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So, I have to calculate an integral with a domain limited by two functions: $r=a\cos(\theta)$ and $r=a(1+\cos(\theta))$ , where $a>0$

The issue here is that I cannot wrap my head around what the integration bounds will be. They are cosine functions so they will not cross each other. One of the two iterated integrals would be from $-∞$ to $∞$, and will yield zero.

Am I doing it wrong or is there any other way around it?

Comment: Do you mean to allow negative $r$ in polar (meaning go backward through origin)? If so some of region would be trapped by that.

Comment: Have you tried to make a figure? It usually helps with figuring out the bonds.

Answer (score 2):

Formula for area inside polar curve is,

$A=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} [f(\theta)]^{2} d\theta$

For your case, $A_1=\frac{\pi a^2}{2}$ and $A_2=\frac{3\pi a^2}{2}$.

Hence, final answer will be, = ${A_1}-{A_2}=\pi a^2$.

Attaching an image in case of a=5.

[image: for a=5]